# Python Ctypes - String to c_char_p to c_void_p and back

Tags: python, string, pointers, ctypes, glib

I'm being unable to create certain C data structures in Python using Ctypes and then read them back properly. Consider the following:

Setup:

```py
from ctypes import Structure, c_void_p, c_char_p, POINTER, cdll, cast

class GSLIST(Structure):
    """GLib's GSList."""
    pass

GSLIST._fields_ = [
    ('data', c_void_p),
    ('next', POINTER(GSLIST))
]

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('/path/to/mylib.o')

lib.g_slist_prepend.argtypes = [POINTER(GSLIST), c_char_p]
lib.g_slist_prepend.restype = POINTER(GSLIST)
```

Example:

```py
py_str_in = bytes('hi', 'ascii')

agslist_ptr = POINTER(GSLIST)()  # NULL
agslist_ptr = lib.g_slist_prepend(agslist_ptr, c_char_p(py_str_in))

print(cast(agslist_ptr.contents.data, c_char_p).value.decode())
# 'hi'
```

The example may be a bit more complicated than it needs to be, but it's been hard to replicate at a smaller scale.

What the example does is to save the "hi" string in the data field of the first element of a GSList (the most common list type in the GLib library). This field is of type `void*` so that it can support whatever type. So, first we convert to a `c_char_p` to make it compatible with `void*`, and then to read it back we `cast()` it.

The example as shown works as expected. It breaks if we do instead:

```py
agslist_ptr = lib.g_slist_prepend(agslist_ptr, c_char_p(bytes('hi', 'ascii')))
```

Simply skipping the assignment to the `py_str_in` variable results in just `''` for an output.

Also, if instead of `'hi'` I use any single character, it also works fine.

I can't really explain what is going on and the documentation doesn't go into too much depth. If I had to guess, something with string literals or garbage collection. But it could also be just buggy code.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd instance that fails is due to `c_char_p(bytes('hi', 'ascii')` being the only reference to the object.  Python doesn't know that C saved that pointer, so after that line executes the object is destroyed and the pointer that C saved is now invalid.  Referencing it is undefined behavior.

In the 1st case the `py_str_in` reference still exists so the pointer C saved is still valid.

Comment: I couldn't see the difference at first. `py_str_in` is not used after being passed to `g_slist_prepend()`, so why would it survive past the function call? But the missing detail is that I was trying this in ipython, where all variables in context are kept alive!

Comment: @jpcgt it was still in use in your example above at the print, which was all the context I had. The key is the data needs to remain in scope as long as the pointer is needed